# How do I get the index for an element in a NSMutableArray in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Simple question, but after literally hours of searching and a few hundred hairs lost, I can't find the way to get the index for an element in an NSMutableArray in Swift.

If someone knows how to do it or a workaround, please, help me out.

I tried

```
var pagerViewControllers = [UIViewController]
...
let viewControllerIndex = pagerViewControllers.indexOfObject(viewController)
```

[EDIT]

Just to avoid confusion and for those downvoting the question, `NSArray` used to have the `indexOf` method. That method was replaced by `indexOfObject` in `NSArray` but you can still use `indexOf` [and it is workign like that now] for `NSMUtableArray`. Actually the line shown above will throw an error, even though parent class `NSArray` does have `indexOfObject`.

This whole thing makes it very confusing if it is the first time that you're working with arrays in Swift, which it is the case. In the answers and comments to this question, you'll see this confusion reflected all over, so I think the question is valuable for clarification to others, and the right answer was selected.

[EDIT]

Comment: have you try `let indexof = yourarray.indexOf("a")`

Comment: The documentation won't list things that are already provided by a superclass.

Comment: `indexOfObject` is a valid method.

Comment: Have you try my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the getting index of an element in an `NSMutableArray` you have the object that you wanted to get index so try the following small code and save your remaining Hair lol

```
let indexof = yourarray.indexOf("a")
```

define array like:

```
var myarray = [String]()
```

do code like:

```
       myarray = ["nitin" , "nitin2"]
       // let index = myarray.indexOf("nitin")

        if let index = myarray.indexOf("nitin")
        {
          print("indexis = \(index)")
        }
```

Comment: wait will give you sample demo

Comment: Yep, you'll save me the remaining hair, haha.

Comment: `indexOf` is not a method of `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: It is @Code. It's indexOfObject that is not. That's what was confusing me.

Comment: in swift define NSMutableArray like `var myarray = [String]()` instead of using NSMutablearray Keyword

Comment: This is the RIGHT answer. I just tried it. It should not be downvoted.

Comment: That's an `Array` not `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: use  `myarray.append(<#T##newElement: Element##Element#>)` for adding new object that's swift not objective c please studying befor doing downvote

Comment: @code please check : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_arrays.htm there is not like ObjectiveC mutable define

Comment: @NitinGohel This question is about `NSMutableArray` though. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)NSMutableArray

Comment: but as an ios dev we have to tel the newbie about right path and right direction anyway its my thought you can go with your :) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

You need to try this method of `NSMutableArray` but if you are using i recommended to use `Array` instead of `NSMutableArray`

```
let index = arr.indexOfObject("A");
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hey, I have to use MutableArray and it doesn't have the indexOfObject method.

Comment: The Array you are using is  Swift `Array` not `NSMutableArray`. Please check what you have created.

Comment: I think you need to read the documentation on swift for `NSMutableArray` and `Array`. First read that and then go for coding.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
  id myArrayElement = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
...do after find your exact Element
 }
```

You can Iterate NSMutableArray and to find the location of particular Object use

```
 int indexValue = [yourArray indexOfObject:yourObject];
```